# PYTHON Query to extract certain info from a list

Tags: python, sql, database

Hi so I have four columns of data that represent the amount of people in my office and each ethnicity is assigned a unique ID and the question is to write a QUERY to display the different ethnicities present in my office.

#### Workers

```
id    ethnicity id
1        2
2        2
3        3
4        2
5        3
6        3
7        4
```

#### Ethnicity

```
id       Ethnicity Name 
1         white
2         African American
3         Asian
4         Hispanic
```

My approach so far is to select the different types of ethnicities present in my offer by using the distinct function and then matching each ethnicity ID with its corresponding ethnicity and displaying it:

```
select DISTINCT class from ethnicity id
```

Comment: Do you mean a sql query? Sorry if I'm not understanding correctly but you could apply a group by method to return the unique using pandas have a look at pandas groupby documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.[Ethnicity Name], COUNT(w.id) numberOfEmployees
FROM workers w
LEFT JOIN Ethnicity e ON w.[ethnicity id] = e.id
GROUP BY e.[Ethnicity Name]
```